# How to create a custom URL as a link for sending mail in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

In iOS, I am using a custom URL Scheme and created myUrl :

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"todo://com.test.CollectionView"];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[myURL];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After that, I try to send mail using "activityViewController" that time url generate without link same as 'todo://com.test.CollectionView' and I click this url but not open app but it works perfectly on Messages.

[image]

I would like to link in to mail too.